# USB Drive not recognized even if USB Drive and Port are working [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, usb

USB drives are not recognized on some ports (drivers are installed).
Why I'm sure drives and ports are working?
Because if I connect the USB drive on another port or PC it works.
So the problem could be the port itself...?
No.
If I connect my phone to that port it works!
I tried fixes and workarounds suggested on internet, no luck.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the controller to me.

Comment: Or it could be a power issue: some USB drives, e.g., HDD, require more power than a USB 2.0 port can deliver.See if the ports that work are USB 3.0. BTW, I've seen some mislabeled ports (USB 2.0 should be white, and 3.0 blue... but occasionally, *not*.).

Comment: Ok, it could be a hardware problem or a power problem, but how the hell the same port can give power and connect to a phone?

Comment: My phone works on every USB port. USB drives don't. I'm getting mad...

Comment: I've seen some HDD's that require a y-splitter for additional power draw, or require auxiliary power (such as through a hub, enclosure, daisy-chain, or other means).

Comment: You say your phone "works" on that port.  Is it just charging?  Or does Windows recognize it as a device?  Charging and data transfer are 2 different things.

Comment: No, no... it isn't just charging. It works. I can navigate, copy or move files. I don't think my phone needs less power than a USB drive.